# Emulate Gmail request using curl

Tags: json, post, curl, gmail, http-post

I'm trying to emulate a gmail request. Basically I intend to fetch the all the json responses.

When you click `Themes -> Change you background image` in gmail, you're presented with a picasa featured gallery from where you can choose the image from. I managed to get the request POST string gmail uses to fetch more images using `chrome developer tools -> Network -> XHR`. And I copied the request as curl.

```
curl "https://mail.google.com/picker/pvr?hl=en&native=1&hostId=gm-theme" -H ":host: mail.google.com" -H ":version: HTTP/1.1" -H "origin: https://mail.google.com" -H "accept-encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch" -H "accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.8" -H "content-control: no-cache" -H "cookie: GMAIL-COOKIES" -H "content-length: 257" -H ":path: /picker/pvr?hl=en&native=1&hostId=gm-theme" -H "accept-charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3" -H "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31" -H "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" -H "accept: */*" -H "referer: https://mail.google.com/_/mail-static/_/js/main/m_i,t/rt=h/ver=NB-HmMH_MVQ.en./sv=1/am=!JjrcIo7GA7b0RPF-I9tbYvMmngnebTyl_O_8x6inji58opxSrbuft8sKd6tLvMR8EoLV76U/d=1?random=1366542355442" -H "x-same-domain: explorer" -H ":scheme: https" -H ":method: POST" --data "start=2050&numResults=50&sort=3&desc=true&data=0&view=2&service=picasa&type=featured&options=%7B%22excludeLabels%22%3Anull%7D&token=MY-TOKEN&version=4&subapp=5&app=2&clientUser=16140887335626099390&authuser=0"
```

When I run this in curl, instead of receiving a json file I receive an obfuscated/encrypted text such as: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8o6zo31klejyvmt/abc.json)

Why the response is not json text like this: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vytjds8z8ld68he/normal.json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is the same you just forgot to decompress the result. If I rename your `abc.json` to `abc.json.gz` and extract the `abc.json` I'll get a result which looks the same as your `normal.json`.

**normal.json**:

```
&&&START&&&{"response":{"cursor":"2100","docs":[{"attrs":{"ut":1.20922026E12}...
```

**abc.json** (after uncompressing):

```
&&&START&&&{"response":{"cursor":"50","docs":[{"attrs":{"ut":1.364824967E12}...
```

Comment: And the reason it is compressed is because the server is being told that 3 different types of compressed responses are acceptable: `-H "accept-encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch"`. To avoid any compression, use this instead: `-H "accept-encoding: identity"`, or just omit the header completely.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I never note that `identity`, but good to know. More informations about `Accept-Encoding` can be found in the [RFC 2616 section 14.3](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.3).

Comment: Or change the curl command line to omit the manual `accept-encoding` header and use curl's own `-compressed` parameter instead so it can decompress the data for you. Some of the manual headers being used have native curl equivilents that should be used instead.